# How to fix error in pandas groupby: No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with a code that try to calculate the statistics of many variables. The curious thing about this code is running with some database and not with others. The databases have the same characteristics, just change the month of each.

```
data = read_csv('/home/mcidas/Escritorio/estadisticas-cea/linux/2011/datos/emas/amealco/enero.csv',skiprows=1,names=['Fecha','Hora','C','D','E','Temperatura','TempRocio','DirViento','I','MagViento','K','Humedad','Presion','N','PreciAcu','P','Q','R','S'],header=0)


direccion=[]
for i in data['DirViento']:
 if i=='SSW':
     dir=202.5
 elif i=='S':
     dir=180.0
 elif i=='N':
     dir=360.0
 elif i=='NNE':
     dir=22.5
 elif i=='NE':
     dir=45.0
 elif i=='ENE':
     dir=67.5
 elif i=='E':
     dir=90.0
 elif i=='ESE':
     dir=112.5
 elif i=='SE':
     dir=135.0
 elif i=='SSE':
     dir=157.5
 elif i=='SW':
     dir=225.0
 elif i=='WSW':
     dir=247.5
 elif i=='W':
     dir=270.0
 elif i=='WNW':
     dir=292.5
 elif i=='NW':
     dir=315.0
 elif i=='NNW':
     dir=337.5
 else:
     dir=np.nan
 direccion.append(dir)
data['DirViento']=direccion

Uviento=[]
Vviento=[]

for i in range(0,len(data['MagViento'])):
   Uviento.append((data['MagViento'][i]*sin((data['DirViento'][i]+180)*(pi/180.0))))
   Vviento.append((data['MagViento'][i]*cos((data['DirViento'][i]+180)*(pi/180.0))))

data['PromeU']=Uviento
data['PromeV']=Vviento

index=data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'])
g = index.groupby(level=0)
stat_cea_mean = g.agg({'PromeU':np.mean,'PromeV':np.mean,'Temperatura':np.mean,'TempRocio':np.mean,'Humedad':np.mean,'Presion':np.mean,'PreciAcu':np.sum})
```

The above code runs successfully but when I change the month (to august) and using the same code, i get the following error:

first when i run the same code, i have problem in

```
index=data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'])
g = index.groupby(level=0)

IndexError: index out of range for array
```

second when i try to change the index

```
index=data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'])
g = data.groupby(level=0)
stat_cea_mean = g.agg({'PromeU':np.mean,'PromeV':np.mean,'Temperatura':np.mean,'TempRocio':np.mean,'Humedad':np.mean,'Presion':np.mean,'PreciAcu':np.sum})= data.groupby(level=0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 304, in agg return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1573, in aggregate result[col] = colg.aggregate(agg_how)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1301, in aggregate return getattr(self, cyfunc)()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 319, in mean return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 408, in _cython_agg_general raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

dataframe for enero

```
Data columns:
Fecha          4464  non-null values
Hora           4464  non-null values
C              4464  non-null values
D              4464  non-null values
E              4464  non-null values
Temperatura    4464  non-null values
TempRocio      4464  non-null values
DirViento      4464  non-null values
I              4464  non-null values
MagViento      4464  non-null values
K              4464  non-null values
Humedad        4464  non-null values
Presion        4464  non-null values
N              4464  non-null values
PreciAcu       4464  non-null values
P              4464  non-null values
Q              4464  non-null values
R              4464  non-null values
S              4464  non-null values
dtypes: float64(8), int64(4), object(7)

 data['DirViento']
 0     SSW
 1     SSW
 2     SSW
 3     SSW
 4     SSW
 5      SW
 6     SSW
 7      SW
 8      SW
 9      SW
10    SSW
11    SSW
12    SSW
13    SSW
14    SSW 
...
4449     SW
4450    SSW
4451    SSW
4452     SW
4453     SW
4454     SW
4455     SW  
4456     SW
4457     SW
4458     SW
4459     SW
4460    SSW
4461     SW
4462     SW
4463     SW
Name: DirViento, Length: 4464
```

dataframe for agosto

Data columns:

```
Fecha          3703  non-null values
Hora           3703  non-null values
C              3703  non-null values
D              3703  non-null values
E              3703  non-null values
Temperatura    3703  non-null values
TempRocio      3703  non-null values
DirViento      3703  non-null values
I              3703  non-null values
MagViento      3703  non-null values
K              3703  non-null values
Humedad        3703  non-null values
Presion        3703  non-null values
N              3703  non-null values
PreciAcu       3703  non-null values
P              3703  non-null values
Q              3703  non-null values
R              3703  non-null values
S              3703  non-null values
dtypes: float64(7), object(12)

data['DirViento']
0     ENE
1       E
2     ENE
3     ENE
4       E
5       E
6       E
7       E
8       E
9       E
10      E
11      E
12      E
13      E
14    ESE
...
3689    ---
3690    ---
3691    ---
3692    ---
3693    ---
3694    ---
3695    ---
3696    ---
3697    ---
3698    ---
3699    ---
3700    ---
3701    ---
3702    ---
3703    NaN
Name: DirViento, Length: 3704
```

An apology for asking so much, but I really want to learn

Comment: Why not use dictionary to map **i** to **dir**?

Comment: Do you have some groups with all np.nan values? Sometimes all NA values can cause issues in my experience. The dictionary idea above would also help you make the code easier to read...